# Django many-to-many field

Tags: python, django, orm

то, что выводит консоль
[image: то, что выводит консоль]
те действия с БД что происходят
[image: те действия с БД что происходят]
вывод в консоль
[image: вывод в консоль]
Сами модели
[image: Сами модели]
Вопрос: Почему после добавления юзера в поле many-to-many показывает что там ничего нет? db.User.None? Что я пропустил?

Comment: Посмотрите в бд, установлена ли связь вообще.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Установлена [тык](https://imgur.com/Yyy9fZe) вроде бы. Дополнительная таблица создалась и заполнилась

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for b in Blog.objects.all():
    print(b.title, b.subscribers.all())
```

Когда мы вызываем `b.subscribers`, то нам возвращается объект `RelatedManager`. Чтобы получить `queryset` "подписчиков" нам нужно у этого менеджера вызвать метод `all()`. Или, например, метод `filter()`, если мы хотим получить какие-то конкретные записи `b.subscribers.filter(date_delete__isnull=True)`.

`db.User.None` выводится, потому что у `RelatedManager` метод определён следующим образом:

```
def __str__(self):
    """Return "app_label.model_label.manager_name"."""
    return '%s.%s' % (self.model._meta.label, self.name)
```

`self.name` - это имя вашего менеджера. Т.к. Вы его не переопределяли, то выводится `None`

Comment: Безусловно краткость сестра таланта, но не в такой же степени. ИМХО, есть смысл добавить немного пояснений :).

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо)